# Comparing sums in a table

Tags: java, arrays

I am working with a double array that is a square grid of any size (3x3, 4x4, etc.) I want to create a boolean method that will check if sums of each row, column and diagonal are equal to each other. If all sums are equal, then the method returns the boolean true.
What is the best way to iterate through the grid and compare all sums?

```
   //check sum of diagonal
    int sum = 0;
    for (int ix = 0; ix < arr.length; ++ix)
    {
        sum =+ arr[ix][ix];
    }

    //sum rows

        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; ++col)
            {
                sumRow =+ arr[row][col];
                if(sumRow == sum)
                {
                    for (row = 0; row < arr.length; ++row)
                    {
                        for (col = 0; col < arr[row].length; ++col)
                        {
                            sumRow =+ arr[row][col];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return bln;
                }
            }
        }


    if (sumRow == sum)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[0].length; ++col)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; ++row)
            {
                sumCol =+ arr[row][col];
            }
        }
    }


   if (sumRow == sum && sumCol == sum)
   {
       bln = true;
   }
   else
   {
       return bln;
   }
   return bln;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Do you have so many of 3x3, 4x4 matrices?

Comment: I know it is incorrect, I'm just not sure how to go about doing it more precisely

Comment: I don't think the order that you iterate things matters at all, so long as you cover all `2n+2` possible sums, and so long as you stop once you have two different values among all the sums you've evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I wont implement the full solution but the comments in the method `vaildSquareMatrix` formalizes your own idea since you are on the right track.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //two matrices for testing (Your can create bigger test matrices if you want)
    int matrix1[][] = {{5,5,5},{5,5,5},{5,5,5}};
    int matrix2[][] = {{5,4,3},{2,3,5},{3,2,4}};
    System.out.println(validSquareMatrix(matrix1)); // should return true
    System.out.println(validSquareMatrix(matrix2)); // should return false
  }

  public static boolean validSquareMatrix(int matrix[][]) {
    //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix)); // useful for debugging

    int sum = 0;

    //TODO: store the value for the total of the first row in sum

    //TODO: check all other rows to see if the total of each row equals sum, return false if a row's total does not

    //TODO: check all columns totals see if the total of each column equals sum, return false if a columns's total does not

    //TODO: check both diagonals total to see if they both equal sum, return false if either diagonals total does not 

    //else return true
    return true;
  }
}
```